# "The service is disabled now." on Synology Diskstation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, synology

When I try to execute phpMyAdmin on my `DS213` under `DSM 4.3-3810` I get the message `"The service is disabled now."`

I have tried uninstalling phpMyAdmin and disabling Web Station and MySQL, rebooting and enabling Web Station and MySQL and reinstalling phpMyAdmin.

I have also reset the Diskstation and re-installed DSM, but I still get the message.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Before connecting to phpMyAdmin to manage the MySQL, make sure you have enabled the Web Station service on the web management UI of the Synology Server.

http://www.synology.com/en-us/support/tutorials/458#t3